# Safety of thunderbird credentials with Firefox and websites with file-browsing scripts on Linux

Tags: security, firefox, thunderbird, sandbox, privacy

I'd like to set up an instance of Thunderbird on a Fedora VM (with a VPN). I want it to use ONLY an alias I have set up with the email providers.

But I will still have to use my real credentials to log into the server. So they are in `.thunderbird` somewhere.

I have to deal with websites on that VM that are pretty invasive by nature (rental tenancy applications like 2apply, snug.com, etc). Each are in a Firefox Container.

They all have the facility to browse your system to upload files and documents, or 'drag-and-drop' - i.e. I have enabled those scripts in NoScript, and I have no choice about that.

I'm worried that information will leak from Thunderbird to the websites, particularly my real email address.

I understand/believe/have heard that linux doesn't allow programs to work without explicitly commanding them to do so, but... haven't I done exactly that with the websites by enabling file-uploading scripts?

How should I think about this? Is it really a risk?

Comment: another thing is, if this is a VM and you *are* worried about separation: why not run thunderbird in a separate VM?

Comment: @ Marcus Müller - Normally I do, but here its for ease of operation. There are a lot of file transfers and copy-and-pastes. Its just a lot easier and less error-prone if its all in the one VM.

Comment: also relevant: https://superuser.com/questions/1376522/can-firefox-script-steal-my-files

Answer (score 0):

> They all have the facility to browse your system to upload files and documents, or 'drag-and-drop'

That is absolutely *not* true. You need to manually drag and drop files there, or manually open them. You firefox will *not* allow a website to just browse the file system – the website never sees what the file selection dialog (which is done by firefox) sees, it only gets the file(s) the user explicitly selected to be uploaded.

This is not even a Linux feature – it's how browsers generally work.

So, you're barking up the wrong tree there; you should still secure your thunderbird with a master password (which is used to encrypt other passwords), but that's really not because your websites can ask your browser to ask you to upload a file.

Comment: This is exactly the perspective I needed, thank you.